# one field is not getting indexed in solr

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am trying to index the data using DIH with sql query

in dataconfig.xml I am putting this-

```
    <entity
        name="slot_data_sunday"
        dataSource="dineout"
        onError="skip"
        query="SELECT 
                        tl_id AS event_id,
                        MAX(CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 0) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_0,
                        MAX(CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 1) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_1,
                        (CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 2) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_2,
                        MAX(CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 3) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_3,
                        MAX(CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 4) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_4,
                        (CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 5) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_5,
                        MAX(CASE
                            WHEN (dow = 6) THEN TRUE
                            ELSE FALSE
                        END) AS dow_6
                    FROM
                        ndf_ticket_slots"
        cacheKey="event_id"
        cacheLookup="ticket.event_id"
        cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" </entity>
```

In schema.xml, I am putting

```
<field name="dow_0" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_1" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_2" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_3" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_4" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_5" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />   
<field name="dow_6" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
```

But I am not getting these fields in my indexes, can anyone let me know the issue here

Comment: Do you have any `<field>` entries inside your entity that refers to the fields you want to extract?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I have changed the approach, so it worked for me thanks

Comment: Please add what you did as an answer and accept the answer, or edit your question so that people who find the question later can see what your solution was.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that whenever we use any aggregaiate functions like max/min in sql query and use the same query in DIH for indexing, it is not getting indexed. So try avoiding use of that. Thanks